# Is there a Javascript library to draw electrical circuit diagrams?

Tags: javascript, visualization

I'm looking for an open-source Javascript library that can draw electrical/electronics circuit diagrams in a modern (HTML5) browser - is there such a thing?  It should have typical circuit elements like resistors, voltage and current sources, capacitors, etc.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked into Raphael?

Comment: @meder: yes, while Raphaël has the needed primitives to let me define my own circuit icons and such, I didn't see circuit-diagram support out-of-the-box.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks to Felipe, Jay, and George for their answers.  It seems no such library currently exists, but the path to make one is putting together their answers, e.g. combine the SVG symbols with a library like Raphael.

Answer (score 4):

Wikimedia Commons has a set of [electrical symbols in SVG format](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/wiki/File:Electrical_symbols_library.svg) and you can search for `svg electronics` too. This is a good start to be used with JS drawing libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a library that does what you want, but there are three libraries that could be good starts.

- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
- [Processingjs](http://processingjs.org/)

They all have the right primitives to start with that you could build off of.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you find a library that has drawing capabilities, then write a plug-in for that library that would draw circuit elements where needed. Raphael is a pretty nice and easy-to-use drawing library.

Answer (score 1):

there is a library called WireIt , it can help you drawing circuit diagrams i hope it helps you or even you can go for webtronics.

Comment: Thanks; those tools are actually on the right track for what I need.  For future readers, the links are: 

http://neyric.github.com/wireit/

http://code.google.com/p/webtronics/

Comment: Found this and was interested but YUI is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DC/ AC Virtual Lab](http://dcaclab.com/en/lab) , more components are added in the near future ..